pandas value assignment of 1 element 1 dimension numpy array set a 0 dimensional array
When setting a cell with a numpy 1-dim array, the value that is actually set in the dataframe is a 0-dimensional array. This doesn't happen when setting multi-element 1-dim arrays:
df = pd.DataFrame({"col1": [np.array([1,2,3]), np.array([4,5,6]), np.array([45])]})
print(df)
for i, arr in df.col1.items():
    new_arr = arr + 1
    print(f"{new_arr.ndim=}")
    df.at[i, 'col1'] = new_arr
    print(f"{df.at[i, 'col1'].ndim=}")

Is this a pandas bug?
I'm using pandas 2.2.2 with python Python 3.10.14
pd: I found this because I'm doing something with numpy 1-d arrays with 1 or more strings, and using explode produced some unexpected results.

When showing code with prints, it's nice if you also show the results of those prints.  We may be reading the question on a phone or other situation where we can't run your sample.

Without the prints, I was under the impression that the initial df creation had this problem.  But it was only after some testing that I realized that is was this df.at[i, 'col1'] = new_arr assignment line that had this probelm.

This is a limitation of pandas, it is not designed to work with nested structures.
What about reassigning to the original array?
for i, arr in df.col1.items():
    new_arr = arr + 1
    df.at[i, 'col1'][:] = new_arr

print(df)

Output:
        col1
0  [2, 3, 4]
1  [5, 6, 7]
2       [46]


Thanks, I'll do it with [:]. Still this behavior is very misleading. I understand is part of the pandas original design, but treating a 1 dim list like structure of 1 element different than one with two or more elements, seems a bug to me.
